# Hover content of a hover()

Tags: jquery, hover, slidedown

I have a simple button which displays a list on hover.

[Working example](http://jsbin.com/agulaq/2/)

I just need to hover the list content, like a dropdown menu. How do I add script to perform that function?

**HTML**

```
<button id="test">Hover Me</button>
<ul class="tester">
  <li>Menu 1</li>
  <li>Menu 2</li>
  <li>Menu 3</li>
  <li>Menu 4</li>
  <li>Menu 5</li>
  <li>Menu 6</li>
  <li>Menu 7</li>
  <li>Menu 8</li>
</ul>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#test").hover(
        function () {
            $('.tester').slideDown(500);
        },
        function () {
            $('.tester').slideUp(500);   
        });
    });
```

Comment: It will be easy to fulfil your need if we get some code.

Comment: @The-Val  i have added my code solve this if you can

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using .hover(), use .mouseenter() on the button to show the menu, and .mouseleave() on the menu to hide it again.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#test").mouseenter(function () {
    $('.tester').show();
  });

  $('.tester').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });

});
```

Edit of your jsbin here: http://jsbin.com/iroxop/1/edit

Comment: the problem is i also need slideUp function when i leave the button (somewhere else apart from the list)

Answer (score 0):

Do You want to do like this?

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/EpV87/25/

just used `slideUp()` and `slideDown()`

Comment: Yeah almost but when i leave the button (Instead of coming into the ul i move my  cursor to some where else  it has to be hide)

Comment: I have updated Fiddle @Jhonny, have a look at it http://jsfiddle.net/EpV87/25/, right now i have used `show()` and `hide()` you can replace it according to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

I just modified Scottie's code for your requirement

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $("#test").mouseenter(function () {
    $('.tester').slideDown(500);
      });

      $('.tester').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).slideUp(500);   
      });

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dolours/mTa6j/

Comment: Dolours same error friend the problem is i also need slideUp function when i leave the button (if i move my cursor somewhere else apart from the list)

Comment: SlideUp function working when you leave the mouse whats problem in that check the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your issue is that the menu shows when you hover over the button, but disappears when you hover over the menu. Try wrapping the `button` and `ul` elements in another `div`, the attach the hover functions to that wrapper. Working example in this [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/ahobew/1/edit).

```
$("#menu").hover(
    function () {
        $('.tester').slideDown(500);
    },
    function () {
        $('.tester').slideUp(500);
    }
);
```