# Drop down menu hiding menus

Tags: javascript, css

I'm building a drop down menu for a project I'm working on, but I don't get it working entirely as is should. I want it to show the sub-menus when I hover the root-level menus, and then close again after a short delay when the menu or sub-menu is not hovered anymore. Most of it works; the sub-menus are showed when root-level items are hovered and it is hidden when I stop hovering the root-level item. The problem is that the sub-menus are also hidden when I move my cursor from the root-level item to a sub-menu item **other than the first** and hover that. This is obviously not good, so help would be appreciated.

I [created a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GANeX/4/) with the code which shows the issue more clearly.

So, here's my code:

**menu.htm**

```
<div id=m_wrapper>
    <ul id=menu>
        <li onMouseOver="show_sub_menu('0')" onMouseOut="start_timer()">Item 1
            <div id=s0 onMouseOver="show_sub_menu('0')" onMouseOut="start_timer()">
                <a href=#>Item 1.1</a>
                <a href=#>Item 1.2</a>
                <a href=#>Item 1.3</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**menu.css**

```
#m_wrapper {
    position:relative;
    display:table;
}
#menu {
    position:relative;
}
#menu li {
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
}
#menu div {
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    display:inherit;
    width:100%;
    z-index:30
}
#menu div a {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    z-index:35;
}
```

**menu.js**

```
var countdown = 300;
var timer = null;
var menu_item = null;

window.show_sub_menu = function(cath) {
    if (menu_item) {
        menu_item.style.visibility = 'hidden'; //Make sure to show one menu at a time
    }

    menu_item = window.document.getElementById("s" + cath);
    menu_item.style.visibility = 'visible'; //Show menu

    if (timer) {
        window.clearTimeout(timer); //Reset timer, so menu is kept open
        timer = null;
    }
};

window.start_timer = function() {
    timer = window.setTimeout(close_sub_menu, countdown);
};

window.close_sub_menu = function() {
    menu_item.style.visibility = 'hidden';
};
```

Comment: Do you want pure javascript? is jQuery preferrable?

Comment: @The-Val: I have never worked with jQuery before to be honest, so pure javascript would be best.

Comment: You should start using little bits of jQuery. The selectors are much easier to read, they're basically the same as css e.g.
`$('#id')` selects the element with the id "id"
`$('.class')` selects all elements with the class "class"
`$('.class li)` selects all li inside elements with the class "class".

Comment: @Psyberion Can i change your HTML somehow to achieve this one? i mean for the demo purpose, then you can modify it as per your convinience. :)

Comment: @The-Val: Go ahead! I appreciate any help! :)

Comment: @gaynorvader: I see! As I mentioned before, I have never worked with it before, but I should probably look into it. I don't really have the time now I'm afraid.. But thanks!

Comment: what differ between this and your code http://jsfiddle.net/dolours/mTa6j/

Comment: @Dolours there is no difference, as we both have replied in that thread :)

Comment: @Psyberion See this link, i have achieved this one using `jQuery`
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16059593/hover-content-of-a-hover/16060088?noredirect=1#comment22919456_16060088

Comment: @Psyberion: I appreciate that, I was in the same boat for a long time until someone pointed out how easy the selectors were to use, then I slowly started building up my knowledge from there.

Comment: @gaynorvader: Yes, I can clearly see how it would be good to know JQuery. But you gotta start somewhere, and since it's based on JavaScript that might be good to know first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to make it that complex.

ofcourse you can do same through javascript, but see how easy, readable and simple it is through jQuery.

See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GANeX/7/)

Just use following script

```
$('#menu li').hover(
    function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({height: '100px'},1000,function(){});
            $(this).find('div').show(600);
        }//gets called upon mousehover
    ,
    function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({height: '20px'},1000,function(){});
        } //gets called upon mouseout
  ); //hover ends
```

and also, I don't know why you have written tonns of CSS. Just use these:

```
#menu
{
    list-style:none;
}
#menu li
{
    width:100px;
    border:1px Solid #CCC;
    text-align:Center;
    cursor:pointer;
    height:20px;
    overflow:hidden;

}
#menu li div
{
    border:1px Solid #CCC;
}
#s0 
{
    height:auto;
}
#s0 a
{
    display:block;
}
```

There's plenty you can do through it, like selected dropdown item. selection through arrow key and what not. jQuery makes it simple for you.

Answer (score 1):

first of all You should avoid `<div>` in `<li>` tags, because is not semantic.

Quite good is multi level menu build only with html and css styles.

**HTML**

```
 <div id=m_wrapper>
     <ul id=menu>
            <li>Item 1
                <ul>
                    <li><a href=#>Item 1.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href=#>Item 1.2</a></li>
                    <li><a href=#>Item 1.3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

**CSS STYLES**

```
#m_wrapper, #menu, #menu li  {
    position:relative; 
}
#m_wrapper {
    display:table; 
}
#menu li {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
#menu li ul {
    display: none;
}
#menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can quite easily be achieved with HTML and CSS alone.  Using CSS transitions we can make the menu fade when we hover off.

**Example**

I have also put this on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MzQ2B/)

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <ul>
            <li>Item1</li>
            <li>Item2</li>
            <li>Item3</li>                                
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
#menu li
{
    position: relative;  
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 15px;  
}

#menu ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;    
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 5px;
    // Transitions for our fade effect.
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out; 
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;   
}

#menu ul li
{
    display: block;    
}

#menu li:hover > ul
{
    opacity: 1;    
    // This stops the transition from happening on hover.
    -webkit-transition: none; 
    -moz-transition: none;
    -ms-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A pure CSS drop down menu

http://jsfiddle.net/steelywing/GANeX/8/

```
.nav {
    background-color: #def;
    height: 20px;
}

.nav * {
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
}

.dropdown li {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: -2px;
}

.dropdown:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that.. if You decide to implement the fade version, You should use crosbrowser opacity, like this:

```
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
 filter: alpha(opacity=100);
 -moz-opacity: 1;
 -khtml-opacity: 1;
 opacity: 1;
```